# If a subspace of $X^*$ separates points, is it weak-* dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $X^*$ its dual.  Suppose $E$ is a linear subspace of $X^*$ which separates points (i.e. if $f(x)=0$ for all $f \in E$, then $x=0$).

Must $E$ be weak-* dense in $X^*$?

In all the examples I can think of, it is, but this seems too good to be true.

If not, does it help if $X$ is separable?  Reflexive?

Comment: If $X$ is reflexive, we can show that a continuous linear functional on $X^*$ which vanishes on $E$ is the identically vanishing functional. A corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem show that $E$ is dense in $X^*$. I guess the case non-reflexive should be more difficult.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are in duality via a non-degenerate bilinear form then $E \subset Y$ is $\sigma(Y,X)$-dense if and only if $E$ separates points of $X$. The argument of the non-trivial direction is the same as Robert's below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is weak-* dense.  The weak-* continuous linear functionals on $X^*$ are, by definition, evaluation at the members of $X$.  If $E$ was not weak-* dense in $X^*$, then by the separation theorem in topological vector spaces there would be such a functional that was $0$ on $E$ and not identically $0$.  Since $E$ separates points, that is not the case.

Comment: For the sake of having a reference: the fact that the dual of the weak-* topology on $X^*$ is again $X$ appears as Theorem V.1.3 in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis, 2e*.  I'm not sure it's quite "by definition" but it is pretty simple.  The "separation theorem" alluded to is a consequence of Hahn-Banach in locally convex spaces and appears in Conway as Corollary IV.3.14.  Thanks again, Robert!

Comment: Maybe a more direct reference: This is Corollary 5.108 in the book "Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's guide (3rd edition)" by Aliprantis and Border.